# PHP cookie gets encrypted

Tags: php, cookies, encryption

The server is running PHP 5.3

My PHP-page is this:

```
<? php setcookie("test", "123"); ?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    document.write(document.cookie);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is this:

```
test=k7NGMNbNAOmUruMOeXDr0mlbmeGCw1Q1T9SwdDpaYw8.
```

What's happening? and how can I turn the encryption off?

also $_SERVER contains this:

```
[HTTP_COOKIE] => test=123
[RAW_HTTP_COOKIE] => test=k7NGMNbNAOmUruMOeXDr0mlbmeGCw1Q1T9SwdDpaYw8.
```

The test page: http://app.npham.dk/test/

Comment: can you provide `phpinfo();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're using suhosin php extension, you can disable it via php.ini:

```
suhosin.cookie.encrypt = Off
suhosin.cookie.cryptua = Off
suhosin.cookie.cryptraddr = 0
```

More settings can be found [here](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.cookie.encrypt)

Comment: Thanks! The 'Suhosin security'-setting on my webhost was set to Low. I've disabled it, and now the cookies uncrypted.